# JavaScript sigma.js graph not displaying in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, visualization

I'm using sigma.js javascript library to display graphs and it works all fine in all browsers except for Internet Explorer 8 on Windows. Anyone knows what the problem may be? Maybe z-index on the div layer I use or something like that?

Here's the website: http://textexture.com

And here's the library: http://sigmajs.org

Thanks!

PS If anyone has Internet Explorer 9 I'd appreciate if you could tell me if the graph displays on there as well.

Answer (score 4):

The library says it supports browsers that have canvas. IE8 does not support canvas support. IE9 does.

You can see if adding [excanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) will make it work.